# RobotFramework - Get Next saturday

Tags: python, datetime, robotframework

I want create in RobotFramework a function that return next saturday.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary
Library    DateTime

*** Keywords ***
Get Next saturday    
    ${today}=  Get Time
    ${today_day}=  Convert Date  ${today}  result_format=%a
    ${next_saturday}=  ????
    ${next_saturday_formated}=  Convert Date  ${next_saturday}  result_format=%d/%m/%Y
    [Return]  ${next_saturday_formated}
```

Before ask this question I try with

```
${next_saturday}=  Set Variable If   "${today_day}"=="Fri" ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using keyword `Get Current Date` you could get weekday index and calculate number of days before Saturday and then using number of days generate date from the future. Final  keyword would look like this:

```
Get Next Saturday
    ${day_index}    Get Current Date    result_format=%w
    ${till_saturday}    Evaluate    6 - ${day_index}
    ${saturday}    Get Current Date    increment=${till_saturday} days    result_format=%d/%m/%Y
    Return From Keyword    ${saturday}
```